# JPA container with eclipse link multi database mapping error

Tags: orm, mapping, eclipselink, jpa-2.0

I have two databases and I want to map tables from these databases. I am using JPA container with eclipse link. But not able to find any useful link to map between two databases. I appreciate valuable suggestions for this. Is it possible mapping between two different databases other wise please suggest any alternative solution. 
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Each database requires its own persistence unit, since a persistence unit can only connect to one at a time.  So the two persistence units would need to be combined in a [composite persistence unit](http://wiki.eclipse.org/EclipseLink/Examples/JPA/Composite) which can allow relationships between the databases.